# How to format excel cells using read_excel and to_excel?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, format

I currently have an excel file named 'excel example.xlsx'. I have 2 sheets in this file.

The first sheet is titled 'Home' and the second sheet is titled 'Sheet2'.

**Sheet 1:**
The first sheet, 'Home', has the sentence 'This is a test' in the first row starting in cell A1 and ending in column D1.

Here is an example of the Home sheet:

`Cell: A1` "This" `Cell: B1` "is" `Cell: C1` "a" `Cell: D1` "test"

**Sheet 2:**

In the second sheet, 'Sheet2', I would like the following data printed:

`Cell: A1` "col1" `Cell: B1` "col2" 
`Cell: A2` "21" `Cell: B1` "23"
`Cell: A3` "22" `Cell: B3` "24"

Here is my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import read_excel

my_sheet_name = 'Home' 
df1 = read_excel('excel example.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Home')    


x = {'col1': [21, 22], 'col2': [23, 24]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=x)


writer = pd.ExcelWriter('excel example.xlsx')
df1.to_excel(writer, 'Home')
df2.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet2')
writer.save()
```

This code works fine but there are some format issues.

**Issue 1:**

The 'Home' sheet printed the sentence 'This is a test' starting in cell B1, not A1 like I wanted. Cell A1 is blank.

**Issue 2:**

The sentence 'This is a test' has borders. I would like the borders removed if possible.

**Issue 3:**

The sentence 'This is a test' has been bolded. I would like the bold format removed if possible.

I am new to coding and will appreciate any help I can get. Thanks!

Comment: This site seems useful: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_column_formats.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) I modified the arguments passed in  `to_excel` to include `index=False` to resolve Issue 1 that you had because pandas uses the first column for an index and interprets the first row of the Excel file as a header (hence the bolding & borders when re-written to an Excel file). To resolve issue 2 & 3 I read the first sheet with `header=None` addition so that the column headers would not be bolded and re-did the data loaded into df2 so as not to have headers as well

The final code that worked for me was:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import read_excel

my_sheet_name = 'Home' 
df1 = read_excel('excel example.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Home', header=None)    


x = {'0': ['col1', 21, 22], '1': ['col2', 23, 24]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=x)


writer = pd.ExcelWriter('excel example.xlsx')
df1.to_excel(writer, 'Home', index=False)
df2.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet2', index=False)
writer.save()
```

Comment: I appreciate your attempt, however, this doesn't work like I wanted. I was hoping the 0,1,2, etc. that pandas prints to excel to be removed. Each time I run this code it adds an additional row of numbers on the top, the top number is still bold, and there is a column on the left filled with 0's. I would like just my data only if possible. I haven't seen anything on this so not sure if it's possible. Thanks @kevins_1 for your attempt!

Comment: If it's the header row that's the issue then df2.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet2', index=False, header=False) should work.

Comment: @kevins_1...Thanks a lot for your help! This did seem to solve the issue. Do you know if there is anyway to keep the excel formulas on the home screen? I would like to use Vlookup in my home screen. The formula seems to disappear when I run this program. I learned a lot thanks to you!